# Optimize "group by" and keep max or min - MySQL/Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, group-by

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
8,00Gb RAM
Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 - 64-bit
MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit)
Python v3.5 (PyCharm)
PyMySQL v0.7.9
Pandas v0.18.1
```

---

Hey guys,

I have a table "test" like that with about 3.5 Million rows which I want to get the rows grouping the numbers using the max or min date as criteria.
The result goes to a DataFrame structure in python.

```
id  num  name  dates
'1'  '1'  'A'  '2017-01-02'
'2'  '1'  'B'  '2016-01-02'
'3'  '2'  'C'  '2016-01-01'
'4'  '2'  'C'  '2017-10-01'
'5'  '3'  'C'  '2012-10-01'
'6'  '3'  'C'  '2011-10-01'
```

Result - **min** criteria:

```
id   num  name  dates
'2'  '1'  'B'  '2016-01-02'
'3'  '2'  'C'  '2016-01-01'
'6'  '3'  'C'  '2011-10-01'
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM (
    SELECT num, min(dates) AS max_dates
    FROM test
    GROUP BY num
    ) AS m
INNER JOIN test AS t
ON t.num = m.num
AND t.dates= m.max_dates
```

It's currently taking about 190s to run in python:

```
import pymysql as db
import pandas as pd

connection=db.connect('localhost', user=user_db,passwd=pass,db='project', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")

test = pd.read_sql_query(QUERY, connection)
```

Is there any way to optimize this query and/or import to a dataframe in python?

As a general question: any other good (fast) practices to import tables from MySQL to Python?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does creating an index on `test (num, dates)` help?

Comment: 12% faster in two tests I performed. Not sure if it is due to the index though. (about 20s difference) I gonna have to try in a larger table. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE t.date = (SELECT MAX(dates)  -- or MIN()
                FROM test t2
                WHERE t2.num = t.num
               );
```

Then, you want indexes on `test(num, dates)` and `test(dates)`.

Comment: The query "select count(distinct num) from test" (which I believe give us the correct number of rows when grouping num) shows about 600k rows - I get the same result with the query I posted.However, the count around the query you suggested shows about 300k.